# Reading and parsing a file with java.util.scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a textfile i would like to read with the java.util.Scanner and parse the content.

> File look like this:
>  
>   
>   Number of objects: 5
>   Description 0 Some description
>   :Description 1 Some description
>   : more description of object 1
>   : Even more description of object 1
>   : more description of object 1
>   Description 2 Some description of object 2
>   : more description of object 2
>   Description 3 Some description of object 3
>   : more description of object 3
>   Description 4 Some description of object 4
>   : more description of object 4

I've gotten so far has this

```
  String pattern = "description";
  String pattern2 = ":";
  int romNummer = 0;
  fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
  do{
      String input;
      input = fil.next();
      romNummer = fil.nextInt();
      String description = fil.nextLine();

      if(fil.hasNext(":")){
          input = fil.next();
          String description2 = fil.nextLine();
          description += description2;
      }
      if(fil.hasNext(":")){
          input = fil.next();
          String description2 = fil.nextLine();
          description2 += description2;
      }
      if(fil.hasNext(":")){
          input = fil.next();
          String description2 = fil.nextLine();
          description += description2;
      }

  }while (fil.hasNext(pattern)||fil.hasNext(pattern2));
```

I want all of description for one object as one string. Is there a more elegant way of doing this with the scanner class?

Answer (score 1):

Why not read each line and then decide if it's a new Description, or if the first character is ':' that it's to be appended to the current Description?

Comment: lines with : means that it's appended to the current description. I've  tried to read line by line and decide if it's a new description but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code

```
fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
String line = "",result="";
int number=0;
number = Integer.parseInt(fil.nextLine().split(":").[1].trim()); 
while(fil.hasNext())
{ 
    line = fil.nextLine();

    Check if line starts with "Description"
    {
         Print content
         remove "Description [number]" from line
         content += line;
    }
    Check if line starts with ":"
    {
         remove ":"
         content += line;
    }
}
```